# reattaching a process started with nohup?

Tags: nohup

Is it possible to reattach a process started with nohup?

For example, start in a terminal:

```
nohup tail -f /dev/null &
```

Close the terminal. Now open a new terminal. How do you reattach the nohup'd process to this new terminal?

Answer (score 5):

You can use tools such as [reptyr](https://github.com/nelhage/reptyr) to reattach a running process to a new terminal, generally speaking though it's a lot simpler to plan ahead and simply launch the process inside [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) or [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) - that way you don't need nohup, and you can connect/disconnect at will.

Comment: I hoped there would be a standard utility for it. Screen is not available on the machines where the command was started with nohup

Comment: if screen isn't available, I assume that means you don't have root access and therefore can't install anything. Which means: you're left with tailing a log file as your "available" options for the circumstances you've described.